# git-svn crashing on big repo migration

Tags: git, svn, migration, git-svn

I've been struggling for a couple of days to migrate a big SVN repo to GIT. It contains about 25000 commits, includes some bad history (moving huge amounts of files due to wrong attempts of branching), non-standard layout (no trunk folder, branches which are not branches in fact so I treat them as part of trunk, no tags...) 
I started with Atlassian tutorial (https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/migrating-overview)
so basically what I'm doing is migrating SVN to GIT repo on my own computer for now. I'll push it to central repo later.

GIT version is 2.7.2.

I tried git svn directly and indirectly with svn2git (based on Ruby)

I've tried multiple approaches but I always sooner or later get:

```
couldn't truncate file at /mingw64/share/perl5/site_perl/Git.pm line 1393.
```

or

```
0 [main] perl 12640 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to perl.exe.stackdump
```

Any ideas are welcome... :)

Thanks!

Comment: Related question: [Error with Git SVN clone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25353316/).

Answer (score 2):

Finally it seems that I managed to get through the whole process and the repo looks fine. What I did and what could be help for anyone who finds this post - I downgraded Git to 1.9.5 and performed all the operations in MINGW 32-bit (apparently 1.9.5 which I downloaded was 32-bit and the Git Bash was in teh same version). Some people on the web recommend to go back to 1.8.3 (that was my next planned step if the 1.9.5 attempt would fail)
What failed before:

-Git 2.7.2 with regular Windows cmd (also as Administrator) or MINGW64

-git2svn (which is in fact using regular git-svn commands but it is very cool if you have non-standard repo layout)

Good luck - but remember - migrating SVN to Git sucks on big repos ;)

Comment: I'm not even needing to migrate.  I just need to operate on a existing, not really that large, repository and the git-svn in the 2.8.x and 2.9.x lines crash regularly.

Comment: Same here, using git 2.9.3 @ Fedora 25: `couldn't truncate file at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Git.pm line 1393`

Comment: ...but without `--preserve-empty-dirs` it's working fine. It seems that this option is broken.